# Pass array values from JavaScript to my MVC C# application

Tags: javascript, c#

I would like to pass array values from javascript to my C#.

Currently I am getting `GUID` null in C#. Not sure where I am doing wrong.

When I check developer tool, I have values

```
http://localhost/mvc/CheckData?GUID[]=C71F952E-ED74-4138-8061-4B50B9EF6463&ColumnVal=1&RowVal=1
```

I would like to receive this `GUID` value in my C# code.

JavaScript

```
function CheckData(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        data: {GUID:eArray, ColumnVal: $('#DisColumn').val(), RowVal: $('#DisRow').val()},
        url: "/mvc/CheckData",
                cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
         ....
        }
    });
}
```

C# backend code to receive values from front-end.

```
        public ActionResult CheckData()
        {
             var GUID = HttpContext.Request["GUID"];
            int columnVal = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request["ColumnVal"]);
            int rowVal = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request["RowVal"]);
    
            string result = (Services.CheckDataRecords(rowVal, columnVal,GUID)) ? "true" : "false";

            return Content(result);
        }
```

Currently, I am getting `null` when it hits to C# method `var GUID = HttpContext.Request["GUID"];`.
I can see array value in front-end. But it is somehow not passing that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Request` represents the request, and to access query data, you will need to do something like this: `HttpContext.Request.Query["GUID"]`.

A more straightforward approach is to let ASP.NET do the work for you is just turn your C# backend to this:

```
[HttpGet("CheckData")] //change the route based on your code
public ActionResult CheckData([FromQuery] Guid[] guid, int columnVal, int rowVal)
{
    var GUIDs = guid;
    int column = columnVal;
    int row = rowVal;

    .....//your code
}
```